# htaccess and url redirecting

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, indexing

I'm working on an MVC PHP application.

My .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /mvc/index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

My index.php:

```
<?php

$url = $_REQUEST['url'];

echo $url;
```

So when I write in the url something like (mysite.com/mvc/help), php prints (help) on the main page. It works pretty well for everything I write in the url like (mysite.com/mvc/index/log) returns (index/log) but if I write (mysite.com/mvc/index) then I've got no errors but nothing is displayed and $url is unset!

I hope I explain it right.
Cheers

Edit: I've made a mistake, (mysite.com/mvc/index/log) returns nothing. It seems like if the first word is "index" it doesn't work cause if the url is like (mysite.com/mvc/log/index) it works and returns (log/index).

Also I've add a line in the index.php (print_r($_GET);) that returns an empty array when the url is like (mysite.com/mvc/index/log or mysite.com/mvc/index), if that can help...

After a little investigation I think the problem is that the word "index" is auto-completed with ".html" or ".php" and I don't know how to get rid of that...

---

Solution:
Here is my htaccess working:

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mvc/index.php?url=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Could it be the third RewriteCond? I always use !-d and !-f, but never seen !-l before. What's it do?

Comment: !-d is "not a folder", !-f is "not a file" and !-l is "not a link".
I've tried without it but i've got the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I've found out how to make it work, it seems like I need this line:

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks -Multiviews
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to this:

```
RewriteRule ^mvc/(.+) /mvc/index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

and change your `$_REQUEST` to `$_GET`:

```
$url = $_GET['url'];
```

Comment: I've tried it with those changes but still the same, I can't figure out why it's working with "indexe" or "inde" but not with "index".

Comment: It's because your second RewriteCond finds that `index` is a file that exists. I would keep the first RewriteCond, and get rid of the other two.

Comment: I've tried to get rid of the other two conditions and I've no idea why but then I've got a "500 Internal Server error".

Comment: @Grexis no the 2nd condition would not match "index". it would match "index.php". unless something in your vhosts/httpd.conf (apache2.conf) is obstructing it. sounds like a configuration or module issue.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, my web site is hosted by 1&1 so I don't know how to configure vhosts/httpd.conf. Should I contact them?

Comment: Hes most likely using .htaccess in root file. If you could, could you edit your first post with your current .htaccess?